How to set up virtual environment in visual studio?
I am trying to start working with django and visual studio but I cannot figure out what are the instructiosns are to set up a virtual environemnt.
How do you do this? I have both tried in a blank file and also in the Terminal.
enter image description here
I tried to both use the terminal and add the code to a blank file

search

This question is similar to: How do I add a virtual environment to Visual Studio 2019? also since I'm not really sure whether you really mean Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code see: How can I set up a virtual environment for Python in Visual Studio Code?.

Not sure if anaconda can solve your problem:https://www.anaconda.com/download/success
conda create -n new_env_name python=x.x.x
Then from VS, choose new_env_name as your executive.

I typically use virutalenv module. More information: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html. It is fairly easy to use. From the terminal, at your project directory, you can follow the steps laid in the guide to create a new virutal environment, activate it, and install/delete external libraries in it
